# How can I add (simple) tracing in C#?

Tags: c#, trace

I want to introduce some tracing to a C# application I am writing. Sadly, I can never really remember how it works and would like a tutorial with reference qualities to check up on every now and then. It should include:

- App.config / Web.config stuff to add for registering TraceListeners
- how to set it up in the calling application

Do you know the über tutorial that we should link to?

---

Glenn Slaven pointed me in the right direction. Add this to your App.config/Web.config inside `<configuration/>`:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" name="TextWriter"
             initializeData="trace.log" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This will add a `TextWriterTraceListener` that will catch everything you send to with `Trace.WriteLine`, etc.

@DanEsparza pointed out that you should use `Trace.TraceInformation`, `Trace.TraceWarning` and `Trace.TraceError` instead of `Trace.WriteLine`, as they allow you to format messages the same way as `string.Format`.

**Tip:** If you don't add any listeners, then you can still see the trace output with the Sysinternals program [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) (`Dbgview.exe`):

Comment: I highly recommend using `Trace.TraceInformation` and the like instead of WriteLine.  Those members allow you to format your messages like `string.Format`.

Answer (score 5):

I followed around five different answers as well as all the blog posts in the previous answers and still had problems. I was trying to add a listener to some existing code that was tracing using the `TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType, Int32, String)` method where the `TraceSource` object was initialised with a string making it a 'named source'.

For me the issue was not creating a valid combination of source and switch elements to target this source.  Here is an example that will log to a file called `tracelog.txt`.  For the following code:

```
TraceSource source = new TraceSource("sourceName");
source.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 1, "Trace message");
```

I successfully managed to log with the following diagnostics configuration:

```html
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="sourceName" switchName="switchName">
            <listeners>
                <add
                    name="textWriterTraceListener"
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
                    initializeData="tracelog.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>

    <switches>
        <add name="switchName" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Code snippet does not work.

Comment: Apologies @usefulBee, it was not meant to be a code snippet, it was automatically marked up as code.  This is configuration code that would be part of your App.config or Web.config, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

DotNetCoders has a starter article on it: http://www.dotnetcoders.com/web/Articles/ShowArticle.aspx?article=50. They talk about how to set up the switches in the configuration file and how to write the code, but it is pretty old (2002).

There's another article on CodeProject: *[A Treatise on Using Debug and Trace classes, including Exception Handling](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/debugtreatise.aspx)*, but it's the same age.

CodeGuru has another article on custom TraceListeners: *[Implementing a Custom TraceListener](https://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/debuggingandtracing/article.php/c5611/Implementing-a-Custom-TraceListener.htm)*

Comment: First link is going to a 404.

Comment: The first link is broken (404).