# CommunicationException. WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, communicationexception

I has a problem with WCF. 
The first application I wrote the example from the site [this](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116764/). It worked good. 
I need to make an application to transfer objects from the server list from the database. But when I get a list of the client, the following `CommunicationException`:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to (localhost:8080). 
>       This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. 
>       This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). 
>       See server logs for more details.

Server worked good or I do not understand something. 
 
If you need information (code) on the project will be, I will give it

Sorry for my English.

UPD:
config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Habra.Server.MobilePosts" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
        <endpoint
            address=""
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="Habra.Core.IMobilePosts" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Habra.Server
{
    using System.ServiceModel;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type serviceType = typeof(MobilePosts);
            Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, serviceUri);
            host.Open();

            foreach (Uri uri in host.BaseAddresses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", uri.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Number of dispatchers listening : {0}", host.ChannelDispatchers.Count);
            foreach (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in host.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}, {1}", dispatcher.Listener.Uri.ToString(), dispatcher.BindingName);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate Host");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

UPD2: 
fails in:

```
MobilePostsClient mpc = new MobilePostsClient();
var list = mpc.GetAllPosts();
```

`MobilePostClient` created by `Add Service Reference`.

UPD3:
IMobilePosts:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMobilePosts
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Post> GetAllPosts();

    [OperationContract]
    FullPost GetFullPost(int postId);
}
```

MobilePosts:

```
public class MobilePosts : IMobilePosts
{
    private readonly IRepository repository = new RepositoryQueries();

    public List<Post> GetAllPosts()
    {
        var list = this.repository.GetAllPosts();

        foreach (Post post in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(post.Title + " loading...");
        }

        return list;
    }

    public FullPost GetFullPost(int postId)
    {
        return this.repository.GetFullPostById(postId);
    }
}
```

Repositories worked correct.

Comment: Can you post the service code and config?

Comment: can you show at what point it occurs? and the config file for your service?

Comment: @devlife You asked me about this?

Comment: Can also include the code for the service operation that you are trying to call that fails?

Comment: Haha.  We're getting closer :) Can you post the code for GetAllPosts()?

Comment: @devlife Well, one must still understand the problem. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set attributes to Post class properties?

```
[DataContract]
public class Post
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Post{get;set;}
```

You can trace all messages with ServiceBehavior [read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
i.e. put attribute to servie

```
[SilverlightFaultAttribute]
public class MobilePosts : IMobilePosts        
{...}
```

and  [set trace output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610/how-to-add-simple-tracing-in-c)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.Xml;

namespace Wcf
{
public class SilverlightFaultAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    #region IServiceBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(" */*/*/* ApplyDispatchBehavior");

        foreach (var t in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            var channelDispatcher = t as ChannelDispatcher;
            if ((channelDispatcher == null)) continue;
            foreach (var dispatcher2 in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                var dispatchRuntime = dispatcher2.DispatchRuntime;
                dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new SilverlightFaultMessageInspector());
            }
        }
    }
    public class SilverlightFaultMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            if (reply.IsFault)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(" */*/*/* reply.IsFault");
                Trace.WriteLine(reply);
                var property = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();

                // Here the response code is changed to 200.
                property.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

                reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = property;

                MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
                Message copy = buffer.CreateMessage();  // Create a copy to work with
                reply = buffer.CreateMessage();         // Restore the original message 

                object faultDetail = ReadFaultDetail(copy);
                Exception exception = faultDetail as Exception;
                Trace.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            // Do nothing to the incoming message.
            return null;
        }

        private static object ReadFaultDetail(Message reply)
        {
            const string detailElementName = "Detail";
            using (XmlDictionaryReader reader = reply.GetReaderAtBodyContents())
            {
                // Find <soap:Detail>
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == detailElementName)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Did we find it?
                if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element || reader.LocalName != detailElementName)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                // Move to the contents of <soap:Detail>
                if (!reader.Read())
                    return null;
                // Deserialize the fault
                NetDataContractSerializer serializer = new NetDataContractSerializer();
                try
                {
                    return serializer.ReadObject(reader);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    // Serializer was unable to find assembly where exception is defined 
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```