# Turning trace on and off, and specifying filepath at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, trace, system.diagnostics

I am curious about the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="logger" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="LoggingFile.txt" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

I want to include the option in my solution to log error messages and the stack trace. But I need to be able to turn this on and off. Is this possible by commenting out everything in `System.Diagnostics`? Or is there a better way?

Is it possible to specify what file the logger writes to at run-time?

Comment: I realise that this was answered a long time ago, but I feel that the actual question of how to turn tracing off at runtime was not clearly answered. The simplest way is to add a switch in the config (named `SourceSwitch` in the answer example), manually changing its value to `Off` and then restarting the application or calling `Trace.Refresh` in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of a **SourceSwitch** which allows you to **trace different levels of messages**. First start by adding some settings to `app.config`

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="TraceTest" switchName="SourceSwitch"
            switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
      <listeners>
            <!-- choose one or use multiple TraceListeners -->
            <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"
                 initializeData="false"/>
            <add name="file" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="error.log"/>
            <remove name ="Default"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
   </sources>
   <switches>
    <!--  MSDN: 4 verbose Information, Information 3, Warning 2, Error 1, -->
    <add name="SourceSwitch" value="Error"/>
  </switches>
  <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4"/>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Within your application you can trace messages by using a [**TraceSource**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) object referring to the definied name within app.config

```
TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("TraceTest");
ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 123, "event info");
ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 123, "event error");
ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 123, "event warning");

ts.TraceInformation("any text");
ts.Flush();
ts.Close();
```

For some common information have a look at [**How to: Use TraceSource ...**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993.aspx) at MSDN. Using Dr. Google I found an related [**question at SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610/how-to-add-simple-tracing-in-c) referring to a [**very good blogpost**](http://olondono.blogspot.co.at/2008/01/about-trace-listeners.html) concerning this matter.

One thing I'd like to point out ...

**To change the level at which a listener writes a trace message**

> The configuration file initializes the settings for the trace source
>   at the time the application is initialized. **To change those settings
>   you must change the configuration file and restart the application or
>   programmatically refresh the application using the TraceRefresh
>   method**. The application can dynamically change the properties set by
>   the configuration file to override any settings specified by the user.
>   For example, you might want to assure that critical messages are
>   always sent to a text file, regardless of the current configuration
>   settings.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. U havent mentioned how this can be turned on/off but it may be in one of the links u included so i have still marked ur answer as the selected answer. Will have a mess around with what u have mentioned above n see if i can get to grips with it. Thanks again for your help.